# SQL Server - How to handle Dutch digraph?

Tags: sql-server

When searching on text attributes I want to support the [Dutch digraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IJ_(digraph)#Collation) which means that any occurrence of IJ or Y can be searched by either IJ or Y.
Example: If I search the text field field1 by "Bye" my results can be either "Bye" or "Bije".

Note: the search should be case insensitive but this is being handle by the collate.

Currently, I'm using REPLACE function to do this, but REPLACE does a full scan of the table.
I want to know if anyone knows a better option to achieve this.

So, currently, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
FROM TableA
WHERE REPLACE(field1, 'Y', 'IJ') LIKE '%REPLACE(@searchString, 'Y', 'IJ')%'
```

Comment: As written, the query will do a table scan regardless because you have a leading wildcard in your search term. SQL has no way to do anything but a scan of the most narrow index containing field1 and apply that permissive search predicate to every row.

Comment: SQL has collations which describe sort and comparison behavior for strings, and some of these issues are handled automatically in the collation.  Can you please explain which collation you are using?  They are listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/windows-collation-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: We are using this SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.
From what I was able to understand there's no collation that handles the Dutch digraph.